# How to run flask app with gunicorn in docker(import local modules)

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile, gunicorn

I inherited a python app that's poorly structured(the majority of the code and routes are in one file, `app.py`. I'd like to modularize the app but first of all I am try to run it in a docker container in order to understand what I am dealing with. I have been unable to get it to run and it fails trying to import some local modules. Below is the directory structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── database.ini
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── functions.py
│   ├── gunicorn_config.py
│   ├── static
```

Here is the relevant excerpt from my Dockerfile:

```
#copy flask app module
COPY app app
COPY requirements.txt ./

#install packages
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

#expose application port
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "app:app"]
```

This is the error I get when I run the container:

```
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2018-12-22 05:51:58 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2018-12-22 05:51:59 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
[2018-12-22 05:51:59 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
[2018-12-22 05:51:59 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in 
import_app
__import__(module)
File "/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
import db
ImportError: No module named 'db'
```

What should I do in order to get this app to run in a container. When I run locally with `gunicorn --config gunicorn_config.py app:app` it runs but not in docker. What have I overlooked thats failing here? Thanks in advance, I really have gone through most threads on here but those imports are the confusing part. Here is a snippet from app.py as well(first 15 lines):

```
import flask,sys,uuidv
from flask import  request, send_from_directory, session, url_for, 
redirect, jsonify, make_response, flash, get_flashed_messages
import json
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os, csv, xlrd
import db, functions
app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_url_path="") #template_folder='static', 
static_url_path=""
app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
locale = (os.path.abspath(__file__))
locale = locale.replace('app.py', '')
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(locale, 'files/')
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error?

Comment: I edited the post include the full stackktrace @nebuler

Comment: What you have seems fine. Perhaps you are using an old image where you didn't copy all of the contents in `app`. Try deleting the old image using `docker rmi [IMAGE_NAME]` and build it again using the `Dockerfile` you've shown in your post. Then run the container and see how that goes.